# Creating links on a page

Tags: links-list

I have an issue that when I create links, in the [[]] brackets, and click on save and close that some of the links aren't created but there is a "/" in front of some of the [[]].

Answer (score 0):

Try backspacing a bit further, preferably to a new line. Then type, do not paste, the text with the brackets.

I think it has to do with Invisible markup or characters.